# When I set load_in_8bit=true, some errors occurred

Tags: large-language-model, alpaca

When I run **alpaca-lora**, I want to fine-tune it with my own data and use it to generate.But whether in generate.py or finetune.py, once I set load_in_8bit=true, it cannot be generated normally. The model will output a bunch of question marks, just like the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85gpZ.png)

I printed out its vector as shown in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boeFm.png)
It looks like it wasn't generated properly at all, but when I set it load_in_8bit=false, it can be generated and fine-tuned normally.

I have installed bitsandbytes and accelerate correctly, and no errors will be reported during testing. I've been stuck on this problem for a week, so I wanted to ask for help, thank you! !

Below is my generate.py code

```
from peft import PeftModel
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM, GenerationConfig
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("llama1")
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "llama1",
    load_in_8bit = True,
    device_map="auto",
)
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, "tloen/alpaca-lora")
def alpaca_talk(text):
    inputs = tokenizer(
        text,
        return_tensors="pt",
    )
    input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].cuda()
    generation_config = GenerationConfig(
        temperature=0.9,
        top_p=0.75,
    )
    print("Generating...")
    generation_output = model.generate(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        generation_config=generation_config,
        return_dict_in_generate=True,
        output_scores=True,
        max_new_tokens=256,
    )
    for s in generation_output.sequences:
        print(tokenizer.decode(s))

for input_text in [
    """Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.
    ### Instruction:
    What steps should I ....?
    ### Response:
    """
]:
    alpaca_talk(input_text)
```

I have installed bitsandbytes and accelerate correctly, and no errors will be reported during testing.I don’t know if any of you have encountered this situation, or what part of the problem do you think it is?

I've been stuck on this problem for a week, so I wanted to ask for help, thank you! !

Comment: one of the options is to set load_in_8bit=False in both generate.py and finetune.py. This will load the model in its original 32-bit floating-point format, which should allow for proper generation.

Comment: You are right, but what should I do if I want to use model quantization? Which part might be the problem?
In addition, if I set load_in_8bit=false, the adapter_model.bin file generated after finetune is 16mb, and the original alpaca-lora weight file is 64mb.I don’t know if this is correct.